# Making sense of $ f(y) - f(x) = \int_{\tau = 0}^{1} \langle \nabla f( x+ \tau (y - x)), y - x \rangle d \tau $

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I was wondering if anyone has a good explanation why this holds. I came across this in the page 17 of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.1537.pdf) (equations at the end of the page): 
$$
f(y) - f(x) = \int_{\tau = 0}^{1} \langle \nabla f( x+ \tau (y - x)), y - x \rangle d \tau   
$$

Here is my understanding, but it leads to different form, which is different from the above: Given a function, the following is the linear approximation of $f(y)$ using the information at point $z$: 
$$
f(y) \approx f(z) + \langle \nabla f(y), y - z \rangle    
$$
Now suppose we want to use infinite many linear approximations to create a smooth approximation for our desired function $f$. 
Suppose this point is $z = x + \tau (y  - x)$. Basically, when $\tau$ changes from zero to one, the point $z$ moves from $x$ towards $y$. This would result in the following: 
$$
f(y) = \int_{\tau = 0}^{1} f(x + \tau (y  - x)) +  \langle \nabla f( y),  (1-\tau)(y  - x) \rangle d \tau   
$$
which looks very different from what I intended to prove.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The desired result drops right out if you apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to the function
$$
g(t) = f\bigl(x + t(y - x)\bigr),
$$
since
$$
g'(t) = \langle \nabla f\bigl(x + t(y - x)\bigr), y - x\rangle
$$
by the chain rule.